# Is there an easy way to get a git reverse log starting from a given commit?

Tags: git, graph, version-control, git-log

Say I have a simple history:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F -> G
```

When normally doing e.g. `git log D`, I get the history

```
D
C
B
...
```

Is it possible to get the view in the other direction

```
D
E
F
...
```

i.e. like what `git log --reverse -4` yields, but without actually needing to specify the number of commits or a particular reference in the history after `D`?

I'm well aware that this is generally not well-specified (because commits often have more than one child, in different branches), but in practice, often enough there *are* some commits just in a linear chain, before there is a branch point. I'd be perfectly happy if only the longest chain of unique immediate children was shown.

Comment: If you can get away with only looking at one branch, something like `git log D^..HEAD`, should work. In this case it would show commits `D` through `G` (assuming you're on the correct branch).

Comment: @Chris: that's a bafflingly evident but good solution, exactly what I want. You wouldn't make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get away with only looking at one branch, something like `git log D^..HEAD` should work. In this case it would show commits `D` through `G`, assuming you're on the correct branch.